# Multiple ring buffer (MRB) with different buffer values according to 2 fields

Tags: arcgis-pro, buffer

I have a shapefile with farms information. 
I know that the size of this farms is increased during last year by a certain percentage. For each row I calculate (according to farm area) the buffers radius pre- and post-growth.

So now I have two fields with the buffer radius values (that are different  for each row).

How can I run a MRB according to these fields value?

Comment: Add a screenshot of your attribute table. What output do you want? One feature/row for each buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the regular [buffer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/buffer.htm) tool twice and use the data in the attribute table as the buffer distance parameter.  After running buffer twice you will have a pre and a post growth buffer layer.  If you want the two buffer outputs in the same feature class use [append](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/append.htm) or [merge](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/merge.htm) to combine them.